# htaccess redirect ignore some patch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have two sub domain

1. subdomain1.domain.com
2. subdomain2.domain.com

and have same root folder. I want redirect all url from subdomain1 to subdomain2 exclude some path. I config file htaccess like this

```
#Exclude some path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path-one/some-link-1$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path-one/some-link-2$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path-one/some-link-3$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path-one/some-link-4$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path-one/some-link-5$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^subdomain1\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Redirect if 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^subdomain1\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But when i visit url **subdomain1.domain.com/path-one/some-link-1**, htaccess alway redirect to url **subdomain2.domain.com/index.php**. If right, i dont want redirect to new url and still in  **subdomain1.domain.com/path-one/some-link-1**.

So how can I do that?

Comment: Your rule looks like it should work. Have you cleared your browser cache? or Are there any other redirects pointing to the subdomain2?

Comment: I don't know why. But if i commented block one (exclude path) or two (redirect) it's working fine with this case.